# Pixel Computing on Core Image or maybe OpenGl on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, cocoa, opengl, core-image

I currently need to compare two NSImage (CIImage etc), and need to get all different colors in the same position and return those position in (x, y) in these two images.

Yep, I did this by getting two bitmap data buffers of these two image, and complete that task in CPU, but I need something like real time processing in 30 FPS, and the CPU get high (around 27%), so my question is can I do this task in GPU by using Core Image kernels or OpenGL, if yes, how can i do that.

BTW, I wrote a custom Core Image filter by writing my own kernels, but it take me 200ms to complete the task, how can i improve it or is there any better solution?

Of course on Mac OS X 10.10 or later.
Thanks.

**[EDIT] #1**

I test for some built-in CIFilters for my 512x512 image, and measure the time it taken, it seems the time are all around 20ms, I wonder can I get better performance by using CIFilters? maybe I want to do in real time like 60 FPS (That's i got 16ms per frame)?

Comment: BTW, I want the output from comparing two image as a linear data types, such as array or something like that, not discrete data. coz i can loop over this return data and save it somewhere.

Comment: I think I have done it, after chain my Core Image filter together, I got all filters run in 20ms, and for 30 FPS, this is acceptable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need it "real time" that implies to me you want to do it to a live stream that will be displayed onscreen. In that case you probably want to do everything you can on the GPU (not the CPU in which case I'd suggested vDSP). Core Image's CIFilter is probably the way to go.

Comment: Thanks for advise. I am using Core Image's CIFilters.